# How to query MySQL Database and display its search results by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and MySQL, can I get a smiple example of how to write the connection string, getting the results from a table with some columns and displaying them? Thank you!

Comment: I know I am being a JERK, but have you just tried googling "php mysql example"?  This thing is OVER documented.

Comment: Google is still better than SO for such questions... if SO is better, then google will show you SO... means Google is always better for such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP manual has full working examples.

- For [the `mysql_*` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php): Full examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
- For [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (a bit more complicated, but more modern and the preferable approach - use this if at all possible): Full examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
- For [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli): Full examples [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: I'm curious, why do you recommended `mysqli` for smaller projects?

Comment: @Stephen ah humbug, I mixed it up with `mysqlite` - I'm not very familiar with both. Time for lunch :) Fixed, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/mysql_connect
http://php.net/mysql_select_db
http://php.net/mysql_query

in that order.  :)