# Search a mysql database and display the results in real time on my site

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to implement a search box in my website, my website is based on users logging in and doing things. I would like to be able to type something into the search box, and then display the results in a drop down that comes from this.

This is a duplicate to [How to query MySQL Database and display its search results by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154598/how-to-query-mysql-database-and-display-its-search-results-by-php) , you may think, it is similar, but I want to be able to display the results in real-time as a new letter is entered.

This function is a lot like the facebook search box, where you can search for users.

Thanks, I have tried to be as clear as possible.

**EDIT: I have tried to find the results, which I can, but don't know how to display them in real time. AKA: a select statement, and that finds out if the name contains what was searched. Then an echo to display it.**

Comment: Your question does not fit within the guidelines for SO.  You seem to be asking for a fairly detailed education on software development principles.  SO is for asking clear, specific questions about specific programming problems.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: you need ajax + onkeypress. Search for jquery autocomplete samples. This is not realtime, I retag your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are referring to something along the lines of "autocomplete".

See **[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)**.

If that's what you want... you use JavaScript to make an AJAX request each time the user enters something in the input, and then also using JavaScript, display the results.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the following:

1. Include javascript in your web page that is executed on each key stroke in the input field.
2. This javascript will have to send an AJAX request to your server with the current contents of the search field.
3. Your PHP server will have to recognize this request, perform a search against your database, package the results in some way (usually as a JSON string) and return it to your page.
4. The same javascript that issued the AJAX call to your server will have created a function that will be called when the response is received from the server.  This javascript code must interpret the result string and update the widgets on your web page with the new information.

Search on AJAX and JSON to get information on how to do this.  In addition, there are numerous javascript libraries which help automate this process.  You can search on jQuery and AJAX to get started.